# Помогите пожалуйста с таким вырезом (справа снизу)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать такой вырез на css, без наложения поверх блока с бэкграундом, именно вырезом, как показано конторум на скрине, спасибо?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688253/reverse-border-radius-with-css3 тут етсь ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант.

```css
body {background-color: #ccc;}

.card {
  --bg: #e1f7ff;
  --bg-parent: #ccc;
  --br: 30px;
  
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: var(--br);
  background: var(--bg);
  position: relative;
}

.card-qr {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: var(--br);
  background-color: var(--bg-parent);
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card-qr img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.card-qr--border {
  display: block;
  width: calc(var(--br) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--br) * 2);
  background-color: var(--bg-parent);
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card-qr--border:nth-child(1) {
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card-qr--border:nth-child(2) {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.card-qr--border::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-qr">
    <div class="card-qr--border"></div>
    <div class="card-qr--border"></div>
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/sOJG5MN.png" width="330" height="330">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Хотя более правильным будет такой.

```css
body {background-color: #ccc;}
h2, h3 {margin: 0;}


.card {
  --bg: #e1f7ff;
  --br: 30px;
  
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
}

.card__top {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-radius: var(--br);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  padding: 20px 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card__bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: streach;
  width: 100%;
}

.card__bottom--left {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: var(--br);
  border-bottom-right-radius: var(--br);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.card__bottom--left::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--br);
  height: var(--br);
  border-top-left-radius: var(--br);
  box-shadow: calc(var(--br) * -.25) calc(var(--br) * -.25) 0 calc(var(--br) * .25) var(--bg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card__bottom--right {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card__bottom--right img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__top">
    <h2>Сотрудничество</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card__bottom">
    <div class="card__bottom--left">
      <h3>Важно знать</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card__bottom--right">
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/sOJG5MN.png" width="330" height="330">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую бро